# What should I do to raise an event after Ctrl+Key click in Windows 10 C# UWP app?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, uwp

I want that, my webview(inside my app) should navigate to a web page whenever user clicks a shortcut button, for example- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> , while focusing on webview.

This is the code I have written so far-

for webview(XAML)-

[image]

for keyup(.cs)-

[image]

This is not working, please suggest any correction.

**Edit**-
As per Mark W's suggestion, I changed my c# code to this-

```
private static bool IsCtrlKeyPressed()
{
    var ctrlState = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Control);
    return (ctrlState & CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down) == CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down;
}

private void taga_keyUp(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsCtrlKeyPressed())
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case VirtualKey.H: taga.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.bing.com")); break;           
}
    }
}
```

This also is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GetKeyPressed method according to the documentation to detect modifier keys.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/keyboard-events

excerpt:

```
private static bool IsCtrlKeyPressed()
{
    var ctrlState = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Control);
    return (ctrlState & CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down) == CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down;
}
```

Comment: Tried but didn't worked, nothing happens when I click Ctrl+h key.

Answer (score 0):

According to the remarks of [`WebView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView#remarks) class:

> As indicated in the Events table, WebView doesn’t support most of the user input events inherited from UIElement, such as KeyDown, KeyUp, and PointerPressed.

So that `KeyUp` may not work well for `WebView`. A common workaround is to use `InvokeScriptAsync` with the JavaScript eval function to use the HTML event handlers, and to use `window.external.notify` from the HTML event handler to notify the application using `WebView.ScriptNotify`. For your scenario you may consider to use the [`CoreWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow) for listening the  `KeyUp` event instead as a workaround. For example:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyUp += CoreWindow_KeyUp;
}

private void CoreWindow_KeyUp(CoreWindow sender, KeyEventArgs args)
{        
    if (IsCtrlKeyPressed())
    {
        switch (args.VirtualKey)
        {
            case VirtualKey.H: taga.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.bing.com")); break;
        }
    }
}
private static bool IsCtrlKeyPressed()
{
    var ctrlState = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Control);
    return (ctrlState & CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down) == CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down;
}
```

Comment: I still don't understood, do I need to use     "InvokeScriptAsync" , with your provided code, and how do I use this code?

Comment: @aryaman `InvokeScriptAsync` is the common way, but this need to change the HTML page. For your scenario, navigate to the site you may not able to change, you could try my code, this is not the way using `InvokeScripAsync`. If you want to use  `InvokeScripAsync` method, please google it firstly.